# How to simulate thermal processes in heat pipes with Ansys

Tags: ansys, heat

I want to simulate two heat pipelines - first pipe is supply pipe with temperature of 130°C and the other one with temperature of 70°C steady state thermal. Both carry water but under different pressure. They are stored in air and in concrete body and laid in soil. I would like to measure temperature at several point on concrete wall and approximately 2m left from pipes and right and 0.5m above and beneath the pipes but the simulation doesn´t work. I already made geometry but the model doesn´t work. I don´t know why (is geometry wrong, eng data, or model itself wrong) because I am new to Ansys and learning everything by myself and from tutorials.

Thank you for any help.

Here is the link for my file: https://gofile.io/d/2diP4m

Kind regards

Comment: It's better to describe the model and boundary conditions fully here, don't expect people to run ANSYS just to understand the question. You can edit the question and add screenshots, error messages and other potentially relevant information.